rational homology of SO(2,1) over number fields
Let $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$ be the special orthogonal group defined by the quadratic from $q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$.
This is a connected non-simpy connected algebraic group.
Now, let $F$ be a number field, and let $G=\mathrm{SO}(2,1)(F)$ be the (abstract) group of $F$-points of $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$.
My question is the following: What is known on the rational homology groups $H_*(G,\mathbb{Q})?$ Is it true that $H_p(G,\mathbb{Q})=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for all $p>>0$?
In a geometric case, i.e., assuming that $F=\mathbb{C}$, Is there an integer $N>0$ such that $H_p(G,\mathbb{Q})=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for all $p>N$? Is $N=3$?
In the article entitled "the homology of $\mathrm{SL}_2(F[t,t^{-1}])$", K. P. Knudson proves that $H_p(\mathrm{SL}_2(F),\mathbb{Q})=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for all $p \geq 2r+3s+1$, where $r$ (resp. $s$) is the number of real (resp. conjugate pairs of complex) embeddings of $F$.
In order to prove this fact, Knudson uses a result due to Borel and Yang (see the article "The rank conjecture for number fields") on the rational cohomology of $\mathrm{SL}_2(F)$. However, the Borel & Yang's result holds for simply connected groups (thus it does not directly apply for $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$).
We can work with the $\mathrm{Spin}(2,1)$ group, but I think that there are some technical difficulties.
Thanks in advance :)

This would be fine to ask about on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions
